# Backbone how to get specific object in array

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, handlebars.js

My API returns a JSON array like this:

```
cars:[
  { 
    "id" : "1",
    "fabrication" : "AUDI",
    "description" : "some text",
    "image"       : "some image"
  },
  { 
    "id" : "2",
    "fabrication" : "BMW",
    "description" : "some text",
    "image"       : "some image"
  },
  { "id" : "3",
    "fabrication" : "MERCEDES",
    "description" : "some text",
    "image"       : "some image"
  },
  { 
    "id" : "4",
    "fabrication" : "PORSCHE",
    "description" : "some text",
    "image"       : "some image"
  }    
]
```

So now, I have this list of data models rendered in a Handlebars HTMl template. My goal is, to click on an item, and then display the details for the clicked item.

Here is the HTML

```
<div>
  {{#each this}}
    <div>
      <a class="item" item-id="{{id}}>
        <h1>{{fabrication}}</h1>
        <img src="{{someimage}}" />
      </a>
    </div>
  {{/each}
</div>
```

The Backbone code:

```
events: {
   'click .item': 'showDetails'
},

showDetails:function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var item = $(e.currentTarget).data('id');
}
```

So far so good, I get the correct id, but how do I get the rest of the data and display them in a new view?

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: do you have a model to your view , showing your view will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that each of your cars should *ideally* be a view itself. So you wouldn't have an `each` in your handlebars, instead you would render an `ItemView` for each model in your cars collection. Take a look at [Marionette's](http://marionettejs.com/) [CollectionView](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.collectionview.html) and [ItemView](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.itemview.html) to get an idea of what I mean.

However, if you'd like to take your current approach, the following should work for you:

```
showDetails:function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var carId = $(e.currentTarget).data('id');

    var carModel = this.collection.findWhere({ id: carId });

    this.$('#extra-detail-container').html(new CarDetailView({ 
        model: carModel 
    }).render().el);
}
```